# Twitter not authorizing my iOS app

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I just registered my app on the Twitter developer site and got my OAuth consumer keys, secret keys, and all the credentials. I'm using MGTwitterEngine & SAOAuthTwitterEngine for development. When I click Twitter share I'm able to log in but can't authorize my app - It's simply dismissing the `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't answering your question directly, but you may want to consider using the built-in iOS5 Twitter framework.  It makes Twitter integration very simple.

The only caveat is if you need to access the Twitter API on your server, on behalf of a user, then you need ReverseAuth which you must be approved to used by contacting Twitter and requesting ReverseAuth access.

Comment: thanks for the reply,i'm pretty much aware about ios5 Twitter integration but my doubt is if i do this it won't support for iOS devices running on lower than version 5.0 right?,i want to support  from iOS 4.0 and greater.